# LinkedIn sharing doesn't work as expected

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm looking for an easy way to share through LinkedIn without all that hassle with OAuth 2.0 which I don't see required when I see other pages that use this kind of sharing (and they didn't required anything from - I can straight out share).

Straight to the issue:

- this one works: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Frefair.me
  [image]
- this one doesn't: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Frefair.me%2Fjob%2F494
  [image]

Seems like beyond main domain I can't get sharing working. For instance from other site a link that goes deeper and is still shareable: https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://bulldogjob.pl/companies/jobs/2043-programista-java-warszawa-bms-sp-z-o-o&title=Programista+Java&summary=&source=https://bulldogjob.pl

I also tested with and without `source` and `summary` query params. Anyone had that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decoded your URL so I could get a cleaner look...

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://refair.me/job/494

So, let's try to visit your URL: https://refair.me/job/494 .  *The webpage you are sharing **DOES NOT LOAD**.*

[image]

*Is your site down for everyone?*  **[Yes, your site is down for everyone.](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)**

[image]

In order to share a URL on LinkedIn, you must fulfill the following minimum requirements:

- **The URL must load.**

If you just want to test out the API, try using `wikipedia.org` or `google.com` as test pages.

Surprisingly, the old `refair.me` URL by itself works fine in LinkedIn, but that could be from some internal cache, from way back in the day when the page once did work.  It certainly does not do so anymore.

Comment: I posted it a year ago - in the meantime site got abandoned by the owner seems to be. Thanks, though!

Comment: @jeand'arme - Actually, I checked the original site, too, in archive.org, your job-url never existed, see: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://web.archive.org/web/2019*/https://refair.me/job/494  This is why your problem *THEN* and *NOW* are the same!  I wanted to post a useful answer, with correct information, instead of telling you to put `og:` tags on a page that doesn't exist (like another post from a LinkedIn dev).  So, if someone finds this in the future and wants to know what happened -- they can.  Do you think this answer is acceptable?

Comment: It is! I forgot to accept it - thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn uses the Open Graph protocol (http://ogp.me/) to determine how pages are shared in LinkedIn.

You may also use the LinkedIn Post Inspector (https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) tool to debug how various pages would be shared in LinkedIn.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find it in documentation and I was suspecting that it's working somehow similarly as Facebook sharing feature.